# Create label background of dynamic strings in Swift

Tags: swift, uikit

How can I design such label backgrounds?

[image]
[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? I suggest looking at this: https://github.com/xhacker/TagListView

Answer (score 0):

You can highlight your text

import UIKit

```
let text = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Hello")
text.addAttribute(NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.grayColor(), range: NSMakeRange(0, text.length))
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 100))
label.textColor = .whiteColor()    
label.attributedText = text
```

Here's how it looks like

[image]

Comment: it is not for the dynamic string i think so

Comment: @NaqashKhalid: What do you mean?

Comment: it is working with only 1 label but when more than 1 label is not working because x and y  are change